# Math domain error in quadratic root function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
def root1(a,b,c):
    return (-b+sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/2*a
def root2(a,b,c):
    return (-b-sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/2*a
```

I am getting a `ValueError: math domain error`, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: maybe if you print the argument to `sqrt(..)` it might give you a hint..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide *complete* example? Like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you have something like

```
from math import sqrt
```

Instead of that import, use

```
from cmath import sqrt
```

The `sqrt` function in [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmath.html) can handle negative arguments.

For example,

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(-4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error

>>> from cmath import sqrt
>>> sqrt(-4)
2j
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the excellent idea of using `cmath`, you can stick to a real number perspective and still create a safe version of the quadratic formula. The expression, D, under the radical is called the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) and has multiple uses in mathematics. It isn't uncommon to see three cases when dealing with quadratics (e.g. when integrating a rational function with a quadratic denominator you need to use different methods depending on whether D < 0, D = 0 or D > 0). The following code calculates the discriminant and the returns a tuple which has either 0,1, or 2 numbers depending on whether there are 0,1, or 2 real roots. The calling code could check the length of the returned value and decide what to do based on that:

```
def discriminant(a,b,c):
    return b**2 - 4*a*c

def quadratic(a,b,c):
    D = discriminant(a,b,c)
    if D > 0:
        sqr = math.sqrt(D)
        return ((-b + sqr)/(2*a), (-b - sqr)/(2*a))
    elif D == 0:
        return (-b/(2*a),)
    else:
        return ()
```

for example:

```
>>> quadratic(1,2,-3)
(1.0, -3.0)
>>> quadratic(1,2,1)
(-1.0,)
>>> quadratic(1,2,3)
()
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point! I plead insufficient caffeine when I wrote it. I'll adjust the code.